# how to modify a full array in mongodb?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, updates

Well i'm kinda new in mongodb, well i'm trying to do something that I really do not know if can be done in mognodb, I have tried in different ways, even I could do as I searched but have not found an answer that can help me with my situation.

That's why I came here, to explain my situation and see if someone can help me, well here is the scenario:

Well i have this Mongo Json structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52b5e332808ab2f802000082"),
"DocumentoBG" : [ 
    {
        "elemento" : "ACTIVO CIRCULANTE",
        "id_documento" : "28223",
        "id_empresa" : "28",
        "orden" : "1",
        "SOP" : "0",
        "3T" : "0",
        "BORA Y AMIGOS" : "0",
        "ARP" : "0",
        "OPBR" : "0",
        "OPC" : "0",
        "LOS FAROLES" : "0",
        "BAR PACIFICO" : "0",
        "ENTRETENIMIENTO" : "0",
        "Total" : "0"
    }, 
    {
        "elemento" : "CAJA",
        "id_documento" : "28224",
        "id_empresa" : "28",
        "orden" : "2",
        "SOP" : "10488.5",
        "3T" : "0",
        "BORA Y AMIGOS" : "0",
        "ARP" : "0",
        "OPBR" : "0",
        "OPC" : "48396.37",
        "LOS FAROLES" : "0",
        "BAR PACIFICO" : "0",
        "ENTRETENIMIENTO" : "0",
        "Total" : "58884.87"
    }, 
    {
        "elemento" : "FONDO FIJO",
        "id_documento" : "28225",
        "id_empresa" : "28",
        "orden" : "3",
        "SOP" : "10488.5",
        "3T" : "0",
        "BORA Y AMIGOS" : "0",
        "ARP" : "0",
        "OPBR" : "0",
        "OPC" : "48396.37",
        "LOS FAROLES" : "0",
        "BAR PACIFICO" : "0",
        "ENTRETENIMIENTO" : "0",
        "Total" : "58884.87"
    }
],
"total" : 3
}
```

and i would like to modify the entire array, validated for the id_empresa, this is the array modified that i want to add:

```
{
"elemento" : "CAJA",
"id_documento" : "28224",
"id_empresa" : "28",
"orden" : "2",
"SOP" : "10488.5",
"3T" : "0",
"BORA Y AMIGOS" : "modify1",
"ARP" : "0",
"OPBR" : "modify2",
"OPC" : "48396.37",
"LOS FAROLES" : "0",
"BAR PACIFICO" : "modify3",
"ENTRETENIMIENTO" : "0",
"Total" : "58884.87"
}
```

if i run this code on mongodb:

```
db.DocumentosBG.find
({
     _id: ObjectId("52b5e332808ab2f802000082"),    
 },
 {
     'DocumentoBG': 
     { 
        '$elemMatch': 
        { 
            'id_documento': '28224'
        } 
 } 
})
```

I get exactly the document I want to modify, but I can not use that code to modify that document, I wanted to see if passing somehow the array modified, can replace the current document, so as I'm sending, I wanted to see if there is any way to accomplish this, i just want to know if there is a way to update a entire array or document with all fields, passing the entire structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understand what you're asking, but it sounds like you're looking to replace the array element where `id_documento == '28224'` with your new element.  To do that you can use [`update`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) with a `$set` operator that uses `$` to identity the index of the `DocumentoBG` array element to replace as the one matched in the query:

```js
db.DocumentosBG.update({
  _id: ObjectId("52b5e332808ab2f802000082"), 
  'DocumentoBG.id_documento': '28224'
}, {
  $set: {
    'DocumentoBG.$': { 
      "elemento" : "CAJA", 
      "id_documento" : "28224", 
      "id_empresa" : "28", 
      "orden" : "2", 
      "SOP" : "10488.5", 
      "3T" : "0", 
      "BORA Y AMIGOS" : "modify1", 
      "ARP" : "0", 
      "OPBR" : "modify2", 
      "OPC" : "48396.37", 
      "LOS FAROLES" : "0", 
      "BAR PACIFICO" : "modify3", 
      "ENTRETENIMIENTO" : "0", 
      "Total" : "58884.87"
    }
  }
})
```